# MYSQL - Create event to delete expired records

Tags: mysql

I have this code for MYSQL event:

```
CREATE EVENT DeleteToken
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
DO
BEGIN
DELETE FROM 
`password_recovery` 
WHERE `date_expires` < 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
END
```

When I run it, I get following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8
```

`date_exires` is `datetime` with format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`
What is wrong with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`.

I tried also `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` but it gives me same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use this query -

```
CREATE EVENT DeleteToken
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
DO
DELETE FROM `password_recovery` WHERE `date_expires` < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
```

Otherwise, when you use BEGIN..END clause, you should use [DELIMITER](http://buysql.com/mysql/42-delimiter-mysql.html) commands -

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT DeleteToken
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
DO
BEGIN
  DELETE
    FROM `password_recovery`
  WHERE `date_expires` < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It is working :). (didn't know about DELIMITER $$) Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set delimiter in your query:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE EVENT
...
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
END|

DELIMITER ;
```

If you use phpMyAdmin, set the delimiter field instead of setting delimiter manually.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Now()` instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`

Answer (score 0):

instead

```
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
```

try

```
ON SCHEDULE  1 MINUTE
```

Complete schecule wil be like this:

```
CREATE EVENT DeleteToken
 ON SCHEDULE 1 MINUTE
 DO
  BEGIN
   DELETE FROM `password_recovery` WHERE `date_expires` < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
  END
```

Comment: When I tried to change, I got new error. IT seems that EVERY 1 MINUTE needs to be written like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DELIMITER`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT DeleteToken
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
DO
BEGIN
DELETE FROM 
`password_recovery` 
WHERE `date_expires` < 
Now();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```